# Replacing vehicle springs with magnets

Tags: suspension, modification, replacements, springs, design

With a motorcycle or a car where the spring are separate from the shocks could I replace leaf or coil springs opposing poles of 2 magnets instead of the springs? What problems may it cause?

Comment: Never heard of this before. What application would this be used for.

Comment: @muse. Well, the leaf springs  help hold the rear diff.to the frame/body I guess in theory it could work with some modifications.

Comment: Duplicate post see this post here :
https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16264/alternator-alternative

Comment: Have you calculated the energy that needs to be absorbed by a suspension system? And the time response? Then how big will the magnet / coil need to be? What have you tried so far? Have a look at the maglev trains. Note this comment was originally posted to the duplicate post by the OP...

Comment: I don't have figures, but I suspect that the magnets would be heavier than the springs they replace.

Comment: What year, make, and model vehicle are you replacing the leaf springs or coils with magnets on?